# VPATH not wotking in a makefile

Tags: linux, makefile

I have a very small make file with content

```
VPATH = src

main: main.o
        gcc -o main main.o

main.o: main.c
        gcc -c main.c
```

Current directory contains a directory src which contains main.c

When I execute make, I get error

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc: main.c: No such file or directory
gcc: no input files
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

When I move main.c in the current directory, it works. It seems VPATH macro is not working. Please let me know the usage of VPATH.

Answer (score 6):

While `make` locates `main.c` just fine, you are missing the use of the automatic variables here:

```
main.o : main.c
        gcc -o $@ -c $<
```

which will be expanded by make to the `gcc` call

```
gcc -o main.o -c src/main.c
```

Always use the [automatic variables](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables) `$<` (first prerequisite) and `$@` (target) where you can, they make make both more powerful and easier to read.